# How do I write javascript Regex in such way it accepts 6 Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Javascript regex to validate that it contains 6 characters and in which one character (1)  should be a number.

```
var pwdregex  =/^[A-Za-z1-9]{6}$/;
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your current RegEx? Do you want that the first character of the sting is a digt?

Comment: Do you want it to be exactly 6 chars long (no longer, no shorter)?  Do you want there to be exactly one numeric character (no more, no less) and the rest alpha?

Comment: Why do you exclude the number "zero"?

Comment: Why do you need to do it all in a regex? Why not check that the length of the string is six characters, and do a regex to ensure that there is one digit?

Comment: @jfriend:yes i want exactly 6 characters long in which there should be 1 character as number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will guarantee exactly one number (i.e. a non-zero decimal digit):

```js
var pwdregex = /^(?=.{6}$)[A-Za-z]*[1-9][A-Za-z]*$/;
```

And this will guarantee one or more consecutive number:

```js
var pwdregex = /^(?=.{6}$)[A-Za-z]*[1-9]+[A-Za-z]*$/;
```

And this will guarantee one or more not-necessarily-consecutive number:

```js
var pwdregex = /^(?=.{6}$)[A-Za-z]*(?:[1-9][A-Za-z]*)+$/;
```

All of the above expressions require exactly six characters total. If the requirement is six or more characters, change the `{6}` to `{6,}` (or remove the `$` from `{6}$`).

Comment: Amazing regex. Adding to favorites :)

Comment: It's surprising that the positive-lookahead assertion can include the end-of-line token and will match the same characters as the pattern that follows!  This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: If you guys like this one, you'll _love_ the ones Jeffrey Friedl used to teach me everything I know about regex: i.e. [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Best book on Regex - ever!"). Hands down, the most useful book I have ever read. Go out and buy this book _right now!_ (After reading this a few times, you may even start using regex to (*cough*) _parse HTML!_)

Comment: @ridgerunner I have this book but didn't have the time to read it all yet! :) I would give +1 for book but I can't :(

Answer (score 4):

All possible combinations of 1 digit and alphanumeric chars with a length of 6.

```
if (subject.match(/^[a-z]{0,5}\d[a-z]{0,5}$/i) && subject.length == 6) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: @maerics Thanks but I think ridgerunner > all of us here :)

Answer (score 3):

**[Edit]** Fixed obvious bug...

If you are ok with using a function instead of a regex you can do this:

```
var sixAlphaOneDigit = function(s) {
  return !!((s.length==6) && s.replace(/\d/,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]{5}$/));
};

sixAlphaOneDigit('1ABCDE'); // => true
sixAlphaOneDigit('ABC1DE'); // => true
sixAlphaOneDigit('ABCDE1'); // => true
sixAlphaOneDigit('ABCDE'); // => false
sixAlphaOneDigit('ABCDEF'); // => false
sixAlphaOneDigit('ABCDEFG'); // => false
```

If you want to do it strictly in a regex then you could build a terribly long pattern which enumerates all possibilities of the position of the digit and the surrounding (or leading, or following) characters.

Comment: This doesn't enforce only one digit and doesn't enforce only A-Za-z alpha.

Comment: @jfriend00: right, how could i miss that?  the updated solution should work.

Comment: Your latest edit still doesn't enforce a single digit.  You could have any character at start or end (including alpha or even non-alphanumeric character).  You can fix by changing your regex to `/^[A-Za-z]{5}$/`.